# TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined - Angular

Tags: angular, google-maps, geolocation, angular-google-maps

I am having a runtime error where it gives me the stack trace of `defaultView` in my angular app, and it prevents me from moving on in my project.

---

**The error:** `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined`

I have googled this, but none of the questions have angular in them. So I think this is the first one about `defaultView` with angular.

I have some code that takes an address and outputs a marker on to the map. I got the error from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

---

**Code in Stackblitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gib2mq.

**index.d.ts** in the root folder makes the import statement work: `import { } from 'googlemaps';`

```
declare module "googlemaps";
```

I also have `@types/googlemaps` installed through `npm install --save @types/googlemaps`

---

I want to the error to go away, but it happens every time I run my app.

Thanks!

Comment: try `import * as googlemaps from 'googlemaps';` instead of your import statement

Comment: It says `'googlemaps' is declared but its value is never read` EDIT: now it just crashes when I use it: Module not found.

Comment: that's a `tslint` error is your actual error is solved?

Comment: No, it is not solved. EDIT: Do I need this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-angular

Comment: your request is not getting fired when I tried with my API key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a pretty big misunderstanding of how to use the @agm package. That's okay! Some notes:

- you don't need this.map or the latlng types. You just pass numbers the to components
- call triggerResize(true) on the map when you need to recenter
- you don't need to explicitly import the libraries in the config...not sure why that is actually. Just make sure the API key you are using has them enabled
- finally, you need to give the map a static height, or its parent needs one (css reasons that I won't get into). You can always set the height with typescript.

Working stackblitz (minus the API key): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yebacm

Good luck!

edit: you also don't need `declare module "googlemaps";`

Comment: How will the `triggerResize(true)` know which coordinates to center on?

Comment: It's based on the lat and long inputs on the agm-map component

Comment: In your case it would be based on `this.lat` and `this.lng`